# Google Charts - tooltip text callback

Tags: javascript, tooltip, google-visualization

I have some charts with a very large data set, so large in fact that when I tried to add tooltip text that would didplay the time in a human readable format in the local timezone, rather than the utc epoch integer value, the script just times out and the browser becomes unresponsive.

Ideally, I would like to keep the large dataset as it is more important than being able to read the time in normal format rather than the epoch. Is it possible to get google charts to fire a callback function to generate the tooltip text value on the fly rather than loading all of them before the chart is displayed?

In case anyone wants to know, my code for converting the utc epoch to the tooltip text is as follows:

```
var utcSeconds = value;
var dateObj = new Date(0);
dateObj.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);

// dateObj is now a date in the users local time zone
var readableTimestamp = " " + dateObj.getHours() + ":" + 
                        dateObj.getMinutes() + ":" + 
                        dateObj.getSeconds() + " " +
                        dateObj.getDate() + " " + 
                        dateObj.getMonth() + " " +
                        dateObj.getFullYear();
```

Any tips/suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was far faster to just use a google 'formatter' instead and change the first column from a number format to a date format and input a date object instead of the epoch integer.

The code for formatting was as so:

```
value = Number(value);
var utcEpoch = index;
index = new Date(0);
index.setUTCSeconds(utcEpoch);
googleTable.addRows([[index, value]]); 

...
...

var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: "dd MMMM yyyy HH:MM:ss"});
// Reformat our data.
formatter.format(googleTable, 0);
```

I would still like to know if you could run a callback though.